# unable to open exe application using java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to open Prom (process mining tool) using java. but it doesn't have effect at all.

```
try {
        new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Program Files\\Prom\\prom.exe").start() ;

                } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this code doesn't have effect.

but when i open uninst.exe in the same folder with same code, it works perfectly

```
 try {
        new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Program Files\\Prom\\uninst.exe").start() ;

                } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i don't know why this is happen. is there any solution?
did java unable to load heavy application?

Comment: Do you get any error or exception while running prom.exe?

Comment: Check do you have permissions to execute the prom.exe

Answer (score 4):

You should check the program output via `Process.getInputStream()` and  `Process.getErrorStream()`, as program could be issuing warning or error messages, which don't lead to an exception. These errors or warnings usually are for missing paths, environment variables, permissions on files and folders, or missing arguments.

```
   Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(
                  "c:\\Program Files\\Prom\\prom.exe").start() ;

   BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Also always check the return code of the process, using `Process.exitValue()`. By convention, zero means that everything went OK.

Comment: +1.  Process.waitFor() could be useful...

Comment: I edited the answer, but the edit got disapproved I think. ...You don't check program output via `Process.getOutputStream()` ...You got it right in your code example though. Anyway... +1.

Comment: @mike Edited by myself, thanks for the suggest